Well ordering every function
I just saw something about how every set can be well ordered, and my first thought at a counterexample was an infinite dimensional space of points, but then you just need to order the dimensions and it's no big deal. However, if the infinity was uncountable it may be harder, but then I realized an uncountable number of dimensions doesn't make sense, but a function is basically what I'm describing. Not continuous, not defined, just all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ ever possible with completely random ordering to start.
You may first consider that starting from 0 going positive, the first time one function is greater than another, it's larger, and if it's equal go negative. However, $f(x)=\frac1x$ kind of breaks this and becomes the largest function, except $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ is the same size. Plus how would the Dirichlet function and $f(x)=1-x$ compare?
My next thought was that I had absolutely no idea.

What's the question?

A well ordering is a total order in which every set has a least element. The standard ordering of $\Bbb R$ is not a well-order, but if you can well-order $\Bbb R$ then you can use this to order functions on $\Bbb R$ in the way you described.

I'm not an expert on what AC allows us to do, but my gut feeling is that there exists well orderings of $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ where either of the mentioned functions comes before any other of the mentioned functions. So the answer to the only part that has a "?" is: We can't say.

There is a fact that seems related to what you're talking about. ZF does prove "if $W$ is a vector space over a field $K$ with a basis $B$, and if $K$ can be well-ordered and $B$ can be well-ordered, then $W$ can be well-ordered". However, this doesn't help much in proving that $W$ can be well-ordered, as producing a basis $B$ and well-ordering it usually requires AC anyway. In general ZF won't be able to prove that the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ can be well-ordered if $|B| \ge 2$  and $A$ is infinite, for example (even if they're both well-orderable).


but then you just need to order the dimensions and it's no big deal

Really? First of all, I don't even see how ordering of dimensions translates to the ordering of the space. But more importantly, any set can serve as a basis for some vector space. In other words you just said "ordering an arbitrary set is not a big deal". No, this is hard, at least as hard as well ordering of any set.

but then I realized an uncountable number of dimensions doesn't make sense

Of course it does make sense. The space of functions you describe is literally of uncountable dimension.
Now, before you well order a set of functions, I challange you to well order $\mathbb{R}$ first.
You see, just because we know something is well orderable, does not mean we know how to explicitly construct the ordering. In fact "every set is well orderable" statement is equivalent to the infamous AoC = Axiom of Choice. And often when we know that something exists, but we don't know how to construct it, it means that AoC is involved.
I've deliberately highlighted "every set", because in some special situations we don't need the AoC to well order a set. For example every finite set is well orderabale without AoC. And so is the set of natural numbers.
But reals are special. In fact there are models of ZF = Zermelo Fraenkel set theory, without AoC, where reals are not well orderable. So AoC is essential here. What that means is that you won't find an explicit formula for well ordering of reals - it doesn't exist. And therefore you won't find such formula for any set of functions that contains reals. And your set does contain reals through trivial embedding as constant functions.
Well, to be honest: it is a subtle mathematics, and it heavily depends on the assumed axioms and definitions (what does "explicit formula" mean anyway?). I encourage you to google about it.
I also think that you are a bit confused, and you may think that reals are well ordered through the standard ordering. Unfortunately it is not the case.

ordering of dimensions would imply that each point can be described as $(x_1,x_2,...)$ and then we can compare the first element and if they're equal, compare the second, and so on, and if all elements are equal, the two points are the same point, but the first one that isn't equal determines the ordering. I meant  physical spatial dimensions.
Assuming AC, the set defined is well orderable, where there is a least element, but first you need to define an ordering system. My question is how that would be defined, such that it's antisymmetric and reflexive. It seems to be paradoxical.

@JacobClaassen what "$(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$" is supposed to mean? You use numbers as indexes. No, infinite dimensions doesn't mean countable dimensions. No, not every point can be described in such way, in particular the space of functions cannot be described in such way. Also "physical spatial dimensions" is just a special case of mathematical dimensions. By far doesn't give the full picture.

Moreover, "the first one that isn't equal determines the ordering" yes, but not well ordering. It is a lot more than just reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive relation. Besides the word "first" already assumes that indexes are well ordered - you are doing a circular reference. Finally "Assuming AC, the set defined is well orderable (...) but first you need to define an ordering system" No. The AoC implies that well ordering exists, you don't need to define anything. In fact, as I already said in the answer, it is not definable for some sets.
